# How to compare rows with each other in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a dataframe `final_matrix` generated from all permutation without replacement of `8`.

```r
require(tidyverse)
require(gtools)

set.seed(222)

x <- 0:7

totale <- permutations(8,8,0:7, repeats.allowed = F)

final_matrix <- as.data.frame(sample_n(as_tibble(totale), 120, replace = F))
```

I would be sure that each row is different so I'm trying to write a loop that check each row with other so `1 vs 2, 1 vs 3... and then 2 vs 3 ...` The comparing function is:

```
isTRUE(all.equal(prova%>% slice(#rownumber), prova %>% slice(#rownumber)))
```

All nested loops that I've tried haven't worked, how can I do?

Comment: Would `nrow(final_matrix) == nrow(unique(final_matrix))` suffice?

Comment: Thanks! Is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

There are two quick ways to check this type of condition for a `matrix` or `dataframe`. The `unique` and `duplicated` functions work for these structures on a row-by-row basis. Thus, you can check this condition with

```r
nrow(final_matrix) == nrow(unique(final_matrix))
```

or even more simply,

```r
sum(duplicated(final_matrix)) == 0
```